# Reading contents of virtual file in /proc

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I need to find a string in the entire Linux file system and I used grep to find all instances of this string in the filesystem. I got two types of results: one from my `/.bash_history` and another set of results from the `proc` directory. It is heavily hinted that the answer lies in some kind of process.

The `/proc` result looked something like this:

```
Binary file /proc/12345/task/12345/cmdline matches
```

When I try to navigate to directory 12345, it does not exist. I read in the redhat manual that files in /proc filesystem tend to be virtual. I'm guessing that the process might have ended by the time grep finished its search and I navigated around to the appropriate directory.
Is there a way to print the contents of the processes in the same command as grep? In this case, it returns two results. How do I read contents of each result?
Thanks!

Edit: I used `grep -rs "*string_name*" /` to look for the string

Comment: Generally, you don't want to cross filesystem boundaries. Since `grep -r` can't do this, use `find / -xdev -type f -exec grep somestring {} +` instead. Note also that blindly using `grep -a` may mess up your terminal.

Comment: What do `{}` and `+` mean?

Comment: `{}` means "replace with whatever file `find` found". `+` is specific to exec, and means "exec with multiple files together", whereas `;` means "exec once per file" - you should generally use `+` when possible, since `fork+exec` is relatively expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm guessing that the process might have ended

Correct: it was your `grep` process that matched.

While your `grep` was running, the command line file looked something like this:

```
grep^@-r^@string^@/^@
```

where the "funny" characters are `NUL` characters separating the arguments.

> Is there a way to print the contents of the processes in the same command as grep?

From [man grep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html), it looks like adding `-a` to the command line will print binary file as if it were text (`grep` thinks `cmdline` is a binary file because it contains embedded `NUL`s).

Comment: So, it's not exactly a match? It's just mirroring the contents of the command line?

Comment: "it's not exactly a match" -- yes it is: it's a file that contains your string (by virtue of your string being a command-line argument). It's not a match you care about, but it *is* a match. Generally, you probably don't care about any files under `/proc` as they are all ephemeral.

Comment: I'm also guessing `.bash_history` is just as irrelevant? In which case, grep did not return any matches I'm looking for. I used `grep -rs "*string_name*" \ ` and these seem to be the only results.